# List all inbound links to a header in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I have an org-mode file with headers and links to headers in it (the links are in the file). Is there any way to list all inbound links to the current header in a buffer, and when I press Enter or click on one item, it jumps to the link?

Example:

```
* Header 1
  Contents of header 1.
* Header 2
  [[Header 1][Link 1]]
* Header 3
  [[Header 1][Link 2]]
```

When I am in Header 1, I want a list of all links in the file to Header 1 (i.e. "Link 1" and "Link 2") shown in a buffer; and when I click or press Enter on "Link 2" line, it jumps to Link 2, which is in Header 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `occur` to find the links by searching for `[[Header Name][` and display the matching lines in an `occur-mode` buffer. Here is a function to automate this (using `org-heading-components` to get the current heading name):

```lisp
(defun my/get-links-to-current-heading ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((title (nth 4 (org-heading-components))))
    (occur (concat "\\[\\[" title "\\]\\["))))
```

Using `org-occur` instead of `occur` will present you the list of matches as a sparse tree in the current org buffer.

Comment: This only works for ascii characters in header, to extend it for non-ascii one can use `url-hexify-string` function, e.g. `(concat "\\[\\[\\*" title "\\|" (url-hexify-string title) "\\]\\[")`. This also will allow search for links in other files, since spaces are URL-encoded when place link in the other files.